# Revisar si un objeto tiene relación con otro en ManyToMany

Tags: python, django

Tengo un par de modelos en Django como sigue:

```py
class Alumno(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField()
    materias = models.ManyToManyField(Materia, related_name="alumnos")

class Materia(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField
```

Lo que necesito es que cuando consulte por los alumnos inscritos en cierta materia, el resultado debería de dar todos los alumnos con un campo agregado que indique si el alumno está inscrito en la materia, algo así:

```py
[{'nombre':'persona A', 'inscrito_en_matematicas':True}, {'nombre':'persona B', 'inscrito_en_matematicas':False}]
```

Tengo la creencia de que se podría lograr a través de `F() expressions` en conjunto con `ExpressionWrapper`, pero no comprendo bien el funcionamiento de ambos. Cualquier sugerencia es apreciada, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Al hacer lo siguiente por ejemplo: `instancia_materia.alumno_set.all()`, te retornara un QuerySet con todos los alumnos "inscritos" a la materia. El simple hecho de que un alumno (instancia del modelo `Alumno`) este en el QuerySet, indica que esta "inscrito" a dicha materia (relacionado al modelo `Materia`).

Comment: Eso lo tengo claro y fue lo primero que intenté, pero necesito es que al consultar una materia, me de **toda** la matrícula estudiantil, no sólo los que están inscritos y que cada uno tenga un campo agregado que indique si está inscrito en la materia que se consultó.

Comment: Es decir quieres un listado de TODOS los alumnos (es decir todas las instancias del modelo `Alumno`) y saber si están inscritos a una materia especifica?

Comment: Sí, creo que no lo expresé correctamente en la pregunta. Un QuerySet de **TODOS** los alumnos que existen en la base de datos, y cada uno con un campo agregado que indique si está inscrito en tal materia, cuando se haga una consulta a esa materia.

Comment: Lo que tenía en mente era algo de este tipo:
```python
materia = Materia.objects.get(pk=pk)
alumnos = Alumno.objects.all().annotate(
inscrito=ExpressionWrapper(materia=F('materias'), output_field=BooleanField))
```
Pero no funciona.